# Adding a mean to geom_density_ridges

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot, ggridges, ridgeline-plot

I am trying to add means using `geom_segment` to a `geom_density_ridges` plot made in ggplot2.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)

Fig1 <- ggplot(Figure3Data,  aes(x = `hairchange`, y = `EffortGroup`)) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(aes(fill = ..x..), scale = 0.9, size = 1) 

ingredients <- ggplot_build(Fig1) %>% purrr::pluck("data", 1)

density_lines <- ingredients %>%
  group_by(group) %>% filter(density == mean(density)) %>% ungroup()

p <- ggplot(Figure3Data,  aes(x = `hairchange`, y = `EffortGroup`)) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(aes(fill = ..x..), scale = 0.9, size = 1) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(  colours = c("#0000FF", "#FFFFFF", "#FF0000"),name = 
  NULL, limits=c(-2,2))+ coord_flip() +
  theme_ridges(font_size = 20, grid=TRUE, line_size=1, 
               center_axis_labels=TRUE) + 
  scale_x_continuous(name='Average Self-Perceived Hair Change', limits=c(-2,2))+ 
  ylab('Total SSM Effort (hours)')+
  geom_segment(data =density_lines, 
               aes(x = x, y = ymin, xend = x, yend = ymin+density*scale*iscale))

print(p)
```

However, I am getting the following error: "Error: `data` must be uniquely named but has duplicate elements". Below is a plot without the means for the dataset I have. Any suggestions on how to fix the code?

[image: Density Plot]

The first 35 rows of data are below:

```
structure(list(MonthsMassage = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 1), MinutesPerDayMassage = c("0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
"0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
"0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
"0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", "11-20 minutes daily", 
"11-20 minutes daily", "11-20 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
"0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
"0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
"0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
"0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
"0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
"0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", "0-10 minutes daily", 
"0-10 minutes daily", "11-20 minutes daily", "11-20 minutes daily"
), Minutes = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 15, 15, 15, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 15, 15), 
    hairchange = c(-1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 
    -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 
    0, 1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0), HairType1 = c("Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", 
    "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", 
    "Templefrontal", "other", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", 
    "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", 
    "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", 
    "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", 
    "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "other", 
    "other", "other", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal", "other", 
    "Templefrontal", "other", "Templefrontal", "Templefrontal"
    ), HairType2 = c("other", "other", "other", "other", "other", 
    "other", "other", "other", "other", "Vertexthinning", "Vertexthinning", 
    "other", "Vertexthinning", "other", "other", "Vertexthinning", 
    "other", "Vertexthinning", "Vertexthinning", "other", "other", 
    "other", "Vertexthinning", "other", "Vertexthinning", "other", 
    "other", "other", "other", "other", "other", "Vertexthinning", 
    "other", "other", "other"), HairType3 = c("other", "Diffusethinning", 
    "other", "Diffusethinning", "other", "other", "Diffusethinning", 
    "Diffusethinning", "Diffusethinning", "other", "Diffusethinning", 
    "Diffusethinning", "other", "other", "Diffusethinning", "Diffusethinning", 
    "other", "Diffusethinning", "Diffusethinning", "Diffusethinning", 
    "other", "other", "other", "other", "other", "other", "other", 
    "other", "other", "Diffusethinning", "other", "other", "other", 
    "other", "other"), Effort = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 
    2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7.5, 7.5), EffortGroup = c("<5", 
    "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", 
    "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", 
    "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "<5", "12.5", "12.5", 
    "12.5", "12.5", "12.5", "12.5", "12.5")), row.names = c(NA, 
-35L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The error message is about your data. Therefore, please [edit] your question and post your data, preferably the result of `dput(...)` (or `dput(head(...))` if this is too voluminuous). We need a reproducible example to answer your question. Thank you.

Comment: Please, can you post the result of `str(density_lines)`?

Comment: No result for str(density_lines) (0 objs of 27 variables), however, when i replace mean(density) with max(density) the code works and I get the following (10 obj of 27 variables). I try to dput even the first row of data but it is too many characters to post here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks for providing the `dput()` result. This was sufficient to reproduce the issue.  `density_lines` was empty because no record does have a `density` value which exactly is equal to `mean(density)`. Using `max(density)`, one horizontal line is plotted for each ridgeline. Is this what you want? Or, do you want a horizontal line for each of the peaks (and troughs, perhaps) of each ridgeline?

Comment: There is another issue. The grouping variable `EffortGroup` which constitutes the y-axis (*Total SSM Effort (hours)*) is coerced to factor for plotting. The factor levels are ordered alphabetically which gives a wrong order. I suggest to turn `EffortGroup` into a factor with explictely specified factor levels in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks Uwe! What I want is a horizontal line at the position where the density equals the mean density for each of the ridgelines. Since mean does not work, is it possible to create an array containing the means (calculated with ddply) for each of the 10 ridgelines and then using a geom_segment that calls from that area for the y location?

Answer (score 6):

### Plotting horizontal lines

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to plot a horizontal line at a position where the density equals the mean density for each of the ridgelines.

The expression

```
density_lines <- ingredients %>%
  group_by(group) %>% filter(density == mean(density)) %>% ungroup()
```

returns an empty dataset as there is no record where the `density` value exactly matches `mean(density)`.

However, it does work for the overall maximum (but not for all of the local maxima)

```
density_lines <- ingredients %>%
  group_by(group) %>% filter(density == max(density)) %>% ungroup()
```

which gives

[image]

#### Find closest value

As there is no exactly match, the *closest value* can be picked by

```
density_lines <- ingredients %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  top_n(1, -abs(density - mean(density)))
```

which plots as

[image]

This plots one segment per ridgeline but we expect to see 4 segments in each of the curve branches (those where the maximum of the adjacent peak is greater than the mean). With

```
density_lines <- ingredients %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  top_n(4, -abs(density - mean(density)))
```

we get

[image]

You can play around with the `n` parameter to `top_n()` but IMHO the correct way would be to group each ridgeline from peak to valley and from valley to peak to get one segment for each of the curve branches.

#### Find value nearby

Alternatively, we can filter using the `near()` function. This function requires to specify a tolerance `tol` which we need to compute from the dataset:

```
density_lines <- ingredients %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  filter(near(
    density, mean(density), 
    tol = ingredients %>% summarise(0.25 * max(abs(diff(density)))) %>% pull()
  ))
```

For the carefully selected factor `0.25` (try and error) we do get

[image]

### EDIT: Plotting vertical lines

It seems I had misinterpreted OP's intentions. Now, we will try to plot a vertical line at `mean(density)` using `geom_hline` (with `coord_flip()`, `geom_hline()` creates a vertical line).

Again, we follow OP's clever approach to extract densities and scale factors from the created plot.

```
# create plot object
Fig1 <- ggplot(Figure3Data,  aes(x = hairchange, y = EffortGroup)) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(aes(fill = ..x..), scale = 0.9, size = 1) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colours = c("#0000FF", "#FFFFFF", "#FF0000"),
    name =
      NULL,
    limits = c(-2, 2)
  ) + coord_flip() +
  theme_ridges(
    font_size = 20,
    grid = TRUE,
    line_size = 1,
    center_axis_labels = TRUE
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = 'Average Self-Perceived Hair Change', limits =
                       c(-2, 2)) +
  ylab('Total SSM Effort (hours)')

# extract plot data and summarise
mean_density <- 
  ggplot_build(Fig1) %>% 
  purrr::pluck("data", 1) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(density = mean(density), scale = first(scale), iscale = first(iscale))

# add hline and plot
Fig1 +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = group + density * scale * iscale),
             data = mean_density)
```

[image]

### EDIT 2: Plot horizontal lines at position of mean *self perceived hair change*

The OP has [clarified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52713272/adding-a-mean-to-geom-density-ridges/52715412#comment92421726_52715412) that

> I want was the mean self perceived hair change (y axis data) for each
>   of the 10 ridgelines.

This can be achieved in the following steps:

1. Create ridgeplot object.
2. Compute the mean *self perceived hair change* for each `EffortGroup`.
3. Pick the values of the created density values from the plot data.
4. Join both datasets.
5. Compute the density values at the locations of the means using `approx()`
6. Draw the line segments.

The mean *self perceived hair change* for each `EffortGroup` is computed by

```
Figure3Data %>% 
  group_by(EffortGroup) %>% 
  summarise(x_mean = mean(hairchange))
```

which yields (for the *posted subset* of OP's data):

> ```
>   EffortGroup x_mean
>   <chr>        <dbl>
> 1 <5          -0.643
> 2 12.5        -0.143
> ```

All steps together:

```
# create plot object
Fig1 <- ggplot(Figure3Data,  aes(x = hairchange, y = EffortGroup)) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient(aes(fill = ..x..), scale = 0.9, size = 1) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colours = c("#0000FF", "#FFFFFF", "#FF0000"),
    name = NULL,
    limits = c(-2, 2)) + 
  coord_flip() +
  theme_ridges(
    font_size = 20,
    grid = TRUE,
    line_size = 1,
    center_axis_labels = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = 'Average Self-Perceived Hair Change', 
                     limits = c(-2, 2)) +
  ylab('Total SSM Effort (hours)')

density_lines <-
  Figure3Data %>% 
  group_by(EffortGroup) %>% 
  summarise(x_mean = mean(hairchange)) %>% 
  mutate(group = as.integer(factor(EffortGroup))) %>% 
  left_join(ggplot_build(Fig1) %>% purrr::pluck("data", 1), 
            on = "group") %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(x_mean = first(x_mean), 
            density = approx(x, density, first(x_mean))$y, 
            scale = first(scale), 
            iscale = first(iscale))

# add segments and plot
Fig1 +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x_mean,
                   y = group,
                   xend = x_mean,
                   yend = group + density * scale * iscale),
               data = density_lines)
```

[image]

#### EDIT 3: Reorder horizontal axis

The OP has [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52713272/adding-a-mean-to-geom-density-ridges/52715412?noredirect=1#comment92647500_52715412) to reorder the horizontal axis appropriately. This can be done by coercing `EffortGroup` from type `character` to `factor` beforehand where the factor levels are explicitly specified in the expected order:

```
# turn EffortGroup into factor with levels in desired order
lvls <- c("<5", "12.5", "22.5", "35", "50", "75", "105", "152", "210", "210+")
Figure3Data <- 
  Figure3Data %>% 
  mutate(EffortGroup = factor(EffortGroup, levels = lvls))
```

Alternatively, `EffortGroup` can be derived directly from the given `Effort` values by

```
# create Effort Group from scratch
lvls <- c("<5", "12.5", "22.5", "35", "50", "75", "105", "152", "210", "210+")
brks <- c(-Inf, 5, 12.5, 22.5, 35, 50, 75, 105, 152, 210, Inf)
Figure3Data <- 
  Figure3Data %>% 
  mutate(EffortGroup = cut(Effort, brks, lvls, right = FALSE))
```

**In any case**, the computation of `density_lines` has to be amended as `EffortGroup` is a factor already:

```
density_lines <-
  Figure3Data %>% 
  group_by(EffortGroup) %>% 
  summarise(x_mean = mean(hairchange)) %>% 
  mutate(group = as.integer(EffortGroup)) %>%   # remove call to factor() here
  left_join( ...
```

With the full dataset supplied by the OP [(link)](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=69397165619155339536) the plot finally becomes

[image]

The locations of the mean *self perceived hair change* for each `EffortGroup` are given by

```
Figure3Data %>% 
  group_by(EffortGroup) %>% 
  summarise(x_mean = mean(hairchange))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 2
>    EffortGroup  x_mean
>    <fct>         <dbl>
>  1 <5          -0.643 
>  2 12.5        -0.393 
>  3 22.5        -0.118 
>  4 35          -0.0606
>  5 50           0.286 
>  6 75           0     
>  7 105          0.152 
>  8 152          0.167 
>  9 210          0.379 
> 10 210+         0.343
> ```

Comment: Thanks Uwe. I am interested in adding one line per ridgeline at the location of the mean density. Is it possible to call values from an array of the means, which have been calculated below?

`structure(list(EffortGroup = c("<5", "105", "12.5", "152", "210", 
"210+", "22.5", "35", "50", "75"), mean = c(-0.642857142857143, 
0.151515151515152, -0.392857142857143, 0.166666666666667, 0.379310344827586, 
0.342857142857143, -0.117647058823529, -0.0606060606060606, 0.285714285714286, 
0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))`

Comment: Thank you for the help with the vertical line, however, what I ideally want was the mean self perceived hair change (y axis data)  for each of the 10 ridgelines. For example, using the data above I know the mean for <5  and 12.5 Total SSM Effort are -0.643 and -0.392. I wanted a horizontal line at -0.643 extending extending from the <5 density ridgeline and a horizontal line at -0.392 extending from the 12.5 density ridgeline, so on and so on.

Comment: Hey Uwe, I am still running into trouble plotting this. First, with the line ` mutate(group = as.integer(factor(EffortGroup))) %>% ` I am getting `Error in factor(EffortGroup) : object 'EffortGroup' not found`. Not sure what to do here? Secondly, is there a way to plot the x axis with increasing numerical value instead of alphabetically? Currently, it is plotting as `structure(list(EffortGroup = c("<5", "105", "12.5", "152", "210", "210+", "22.5", "35", "50", "75"), ` but I want <5, 12.5, 22.5 and so forth.

Comment: @jbearazesh, Your sample dataset did include a variable `EffortGroup` which subsequently is used in my answer. Please, doublecheck if this variable is included in your data (or is spelled differently). Concerning the order of the x-axis, please, see my respective [comment on your question of Oct 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52713272/adding-a-mean-to-geom-density-ridges/52715412?noredirect=1#comment92356631_52713272).

Comment: Thanks. I still have `EffortGroup` in my dataset and when it is called earlier in the `ggplot` line it works fine. It may have to do with the fact I cannot replicate the mean self perceived hair change for each EffortGroup using the code you provided `Figure3Data %>% 
  group_by(EffortGroup) %>% 
  summarise(x_mean = mean(hairchange))`

This yields 0.02, which is the mean of the entire dataset

Comment: @jbearazesh Debugging without access to your full dataset is quite difficult. Any chance to make your full dataset available for download? Perhaps, you may find my 3rd edit useful.

Comment: 3rd edit extremely helpful. Full dataset: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=69397165619155339536

Comment: @jbearazesh Thank you for providing the full dataset. I was able to create the final plot without problems.